# Deserialize PrimaryKey (DynamoDB) with Jackson

Tags: jackson, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

An error is thrown when I'm trying to deserialize PrimaryKey (serialization goes well with Jackson).

I'm trying the following:

```
Myobject myObject =(Myobject) mapper.convertValue(obj.get("myObject"), MyObject.class);
```

with object:

```
public class MyObject {

    private PrimaryKey primaryKey;
    private String attributeName;
    private String metaDataFieldName;
    private long numRepeated;
```

And getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: com.scanner.dynamodb.DynamoDBDataLink["primaryKey"]->com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.PrimaryKey["componentNameSet"]->java.util.LinkedKeySet[0])
```

Thanks

Comment: Show PrimaryKey class code.

Comment: This is missing a bunch of information...full stack trace? what is `obj`? Provide all the associated context.